# JAVASCRIPT : Parameter Passed Is "Not Defined"

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a page that should read data from the database, display it as a table, and allow row-wise editing of the entries (using AJAX calls). Here are brief code snippets where the problem comes -

Javascript:

```
function editParam(bname, button) {
 alert(bname); //this part doesn't happen, the error on console comes up before it
 tr = button.parentNode;
 while (tr && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR" && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "BODY") {
    tr = tr.parentNode;
 }
 if (!tr || tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR") {
    return; 
 }
 //some more code
}
```

PHP:

```
//get $row_users['Name']
while ($row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
 echo "<form method='POST'> //some <tr><td></td></tr>
 <button onclick='editParam(".$row_users['Name'].", this)'>Edit</button>
 </form>";
}
```

My data in the column Name is like "B1", "C2", etc.

Error onclick of button : **B1 is not defined.**

While running the code for other text or numbers, it worked fine. So I understand that my problem has to do with the datatype. However, I do not know how resolve the same.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to pass a string to the function.

Comment: @CBroe could you please explain how so in this case?

Comment: You're dumping out the name, so the resulting attribute value looks like `editParam(B1, this)` - should be `editParam("B1", this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes around `$row_users['Name']` since otherwise it is interpreted as a JS variable.

```
"<button onclick='editParam(\"" . $row_users['Name'] . "\", this)'>Edit</button>";
```